# Cannot display JSON API result from console to html page

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, typescript

Cannot display the console result in the html page
and this is the code of the TS component (home.component.ts)

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'; 
import {Router   } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor( 
    
    private http: Http,
    public router:Router
    
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  
source="";
destination="";
date="";
names="";
searchCity(){
this.http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/restapi/?source="+this.source+"&destination="+this.destination+"&date="+this.date+"")
.subscribe(
 (res:Response) => {
   this.router.navigate(['test']);
   const searchFlight= res.json();
   console.log(searchFlight);
   //this.names = searchFlight.names; 
 }
)
}
}
```

This is the page where i want to display the result (test page) (this.router.navigate(['test']);)
(test.component.html)

```html
 <div class="hl1"></div>
{{names}}
{{prices}}
<div class="hl1"></div>
```

and thess are the params i get 
(home.component.html)

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="From ..." [(ngModel)]=source name="source">

<input type="text" placeholder="To ..." [(ngModel)]=destination name="destination">

<input type="text" class="input datepicker" value="Mm/Dd/Yy" [(ngModel)]=date name="date">

 <button (click)=searchCity() type="submit">Search</button>
```

and this is the console result 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f87ht.png)

Comment: So where is the code the `test` route's component? Or does it route to the same component?

Comment: after the search, it will be redirect to the test html page with the console result

Comment: Can you put this up on StackBlitz pls? [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Answer (score 0):

Conosole.log is to show debug prints in Console no in HTML.

To see the service results in HTML you must to get them from response object
example:

... first init you variables to see them on html

```
this.names = "Sample"
this.prices = 5;
```

... then apply this code inside your function

```
this.http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/restapi/?source="+this.source+"&destination="+this.destination+"&date="+this.date+"")
.subscribe(
 (res:Response) => {
   this.router.navigate(['test']);
   searchFlight= res.json();
   console.log(searchFlight);

   this.names = searchFlight.names;
   this.prices = searchFlight.prices;
 }
)
```

... **Advice**: check you api result, and check if you problem is just update the DOM

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to see the data will only show you on the Console.  You can use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) and you can see the object.  If you need to print it on the screen you can do something like this:

```
...
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
constructor( private http: Http, public router:Router ) {}

ngOnInit(){}

get printObject() {return JSON.stringify(this.object)};  //set this method
```

and you can use this in your template like

```
<div> {{printObject}} </div>
```

What this does is sets a method on the controller that returns a stringified representation of the object.  If you have an array, try something like this in your template

```
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let object of array">{{object | json}}</li>
</ul>
```